# jQuery Convert a div's text into vertical

Tags: jquery

Lets say i got this div

```
<div>
    Convert This into a vertical Text
</div>
```

While searching for a way in which i can convert this text into a vertical text.

I found out something like this :

```
$('div').html($('div').text().replace(/(.)/g,"$1<br />"));
```

This works.
But is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: @Pehmolelu rotate would not work, the text needs to be written _down_ the page, one letter under another.

Comment: Ah yeah misunderstood the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put a space between each character, and then give the div a very narrow width see this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3dFgg/1/

Comment: Yea it works like what i want. :D But i will give the width `1ex` :D

Answer (score 4):

```
$('div').text(function(i, text) {
    return $.trim(text).split('').join('\n');
}).css('white-space', 'pre');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/bkeSE/).

Substitute the `div` selector with whatever you need.

Comment: This is cool, but the OP might need to only do it for one div. (+1)

Comment: @kritya I changed the solution to not use `br` element.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div').html( $('div').text().split('').join('<br />') );
```

Comment: I dont want to use br and this is almost this same :O

Comment: Then the only way to do it would be to put a space between each character, and then give the div a very narrow width, like @3nigma suggested.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
$('div').css('-moz-transform','rotate(90deg)');
$('div').css('-webkit-transform','rotate(90deg)');
$('div').css('-o-transform','rotate(90deg)');
$('div').css('writing-mode','tb-rl');
```

or

```
<style>
.vert_text{
 -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
 writing-mode: tb-rl;
}
</style>

$('div').toggleClass('vert_text');
```

Comment: By the look of the OP's example, they want the characters in standard orientation, but only one per line.

Comment: Not working. And i also want the text below another. And not rotate it. And css3 isnt functional at the old browsers. Sooo